# How to print out if a number is positive or negative without using If statement

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl, and currently I'm doing some basic exercises, one that is proposed is to insert a number and print out if it is positive or negative, without using if statements. I know how to do the logic, but I don't know how to print the output without using an if statement.

Comment: Is this an exercise in finding alternatives to "if", or an exercise in Perl's math functions?

Comment: I'm disappointed to see that there isn't a single answer suggesting to use `unless`. I think that it shows how popular and commonly used `unless` is...

Comment: @Dada Well, unless is just if reversed. `if (! whatever)`, I feel that is in violation of the premises

Comment: @TLP Well, given that your comment never got addressed, I feel like unless told otherwise by OP, `unless` is perfectly valid. I also think that `while ($n >= 0) { print "positive"; break; } while ($n < 0) { print "negative"; break }` is a valid answer as well, even though `while` isn't much more than `if`+`goto`. Is my suggestion to use `unless` very cheap? Yes. Is it invalid? I'd vote no :D

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to @clamp's answer in that it uses a look-up (array instead of hash here), but uses the `<=>` numeric comparison operator:

> Binary "<=>" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right argument.

It also relies on the use of a `-1` subscript to an array referring to the last element of an array.

```
my @res = qw(zero positive negative);
say "$_ is ", $res[$_ <=> 0] for -42, 24, 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookup hash and a little math:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.20.0;

my %res = (-1 => 'negative',
           1  => 'positive',
           0 => 'zero'
       );

for (-42,24,0){
    my $res = $res{$_/(abs $_ || 1)};
    say "number $_ is $res";
}
```

number -42 is negative

number 24 is positive

number 0 is zero

Comment: I'd make it a separate answer, but it's essentially the same as yours but not as polite:
`my @res = qw(zero positive negative); say "$_ is ", $res[$_ <=> 0] for -42, 24, 0;`

Comment: @Jim Davis binary `<=>` is a different approach. That should be a seperate answer.

Comment: Stringifying, and doing an arithmetic operation? Not efficient, surely?

Comment: @Ed.  Inefficient for sure. But to me the question seemed to be about alternatives to an if construct. - Still waiting for a regex solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [conditional operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.34.1/perlop#Conditional-Operator).

For example:

```
perl -E '$n=42; say $n==0 ? "zero" : $n<0 ? "negative" : "positive"'
positive

perl -E '$n=-42; say $n==0 ? "zero" : $n<0 ? "negative" : "positive"'
negative

perl -E '$n=0; say $n==0 ? "zero" : $n<0 ? "negative" : "positive"'
zero
```

Comment: Or if the conditional operator is too normal, `$n<0 && "negative" || $n>0 && "positive" || "zero"`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `print $number >= 0? "Positive":"Negative";`